# Azure: List OS Images

Tags: azure, operating-system, http-headers, azure-virtual-machine

Im new to windows azure,
Ive looked to this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157191.aspx), to me it works, Listing Images on gallery.
https://management.core.windows.net/subscription-id/services/images

But this isnt what Im looking for, Is there a way to list the My Images on my account and not the images on gallery.

Answer (score 9):

If you run the PowerShell cmdlet `Get-AzureVMImage`, you'll see *all* images. As stated by @Gaurav, The ones that correlate to **My Images** have a PublisherName of **User**. So, again, using PowerShell, here's how to see just your images by piping to `Where-Object`:

```
Get-AzureVMImage | Where-Object { $_.PublisherName -eq 'User' }
```

If you wanted to see the image names in your console, you could pipe it to `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-AzureVMImage | Where-Object { $_.PublisherName -eq 'User' } |
ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.ImageName }
```

Note:
If your image's PublisherName is empty, use Category -eq 'User' instead.

Here's sample output, from my subscription:

[image: Output of 'My Images']

**EDIT**
If you're using the Mac/Linux CLI, you'd run a slightly different command:

```
azure vm image list
```

Or, to return json:

```
azure vm image list --json
```

Once you have json, you could, for example, pipe to a command line tool such as [jsontool](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsontool) to get your own image names (the image name is returned in the `Name` key):

```
azure vm image list --json | json -a -c 'this.Category == "User"' Name
```

Comment: Hello can you help me how to filter this using REST api. thanks

Comment: is there a way to get the list using Linux CLI?

Comment: @GuyKorland - I just updated my answer with the Mac/Linux CLI method.

Answer (score 1):

You would still use the same operation. The operation returns both system defined (i.e. gallery) and user defined images. To see only the user defined images, you would need to filter on `PublisherName` which would be `User` for user defined images. This is what the documentation states:

> PublisherName: The name of the publisher of the image. All user images
>   have a publisher name of User.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command. It works with *Category* as *User* rather than publisher name.

Solution:

```
Get-AzureVMImage | Where-Object { $_.Category -match 'User'} | 
ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.ImageName }
```