# How to find Windows Azure Image IDs?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

How can I find the publicly available Image IDs on Windows Azure?

I found this related question - [Azure: List OS Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965779/azure-list-os-images)

But, the answer requires Windows+PowerShell while I need a way to get it on Linux or REST/

Comment: I updated my answer on the other question to show Mac/Linux CLI syntax. Probably best to close/delete this duplicate question at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the URL specified here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157191.aspx

You'll need to provide a client certificate when sending the request.
If you are using curl on Linux, add the `--cert` to point to a .pem file (you'll need to upload it to the administrator's management certificate as a .cer file first).
Don't forget to add the x-ms-version header for it to work:

```
-H "x-ms-version: 2013-03-01"
```

Here is an example of using curl to get the auto-scale information for a cloud service

```
curl -H "accept: application/json" -H "x-ms-version: 2013-10-01"
--cert azure-cert.pem $AUTOSCALEURL
```